# Misplaced coordinates in `TikZ` diagram using `calc` library

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, a five-pointed star and the regular pentagon it circumscribes is drawn. According to Eric Weisstein of Wolfram, if each edge of the five-pointed star is 1, the distance between each point of the star and its nearest vertex of the pentagram is `(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5)) \approx 0.382`, and the radius of the circle that circumscribes the five-pointed star is `sqrt((1/10)*(5 - sqrt(5))) \approx 0.526`.  The points of the star are labeled `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, and `A` is located at `(-126:0.526)` with respect to the center of the circle.

A trapezoid is to be shaded. Its vertices are two vertices of the pentagon and two vertices of the five-pointed star. One vertex of the trapezoid is on line segment `AD`, and another vertex of the trapezoid is on line segment `BE`.

```
\coordinate (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) ($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);
\coordinate (another_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) ($(B)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);
```

It looks like both of these coordinates are placed at the center of the circle. Why did that happen? (The other two vertices of the trapezoid are `C` and `E`.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (center_of_pentagon) at (0,0);
\draw ($(center_of_pentagon) +(-126:{sqrt((1/10)*(5 - sqrt(5)))})$) coordinate (A)
-- ($(center_of_pentagon) +(-54:{sqrt((1/10)*(5 - sqrt(5)))})$) coordinate (B)
-- ($(center_of_pentagon) +(18:{sqrt((1/10)*(5 - sqrt(5)))})$) coordinate (C)
-- ($(center_of_pentagon) +(0,{sqrt((1/10)*(5 - sqrt(5)))})$) coordinate (D)
-- ($(center_of_pentagon) +(162:{sqrt((1/10)*(5 - sqrt(5)))})$) coordinate (E) -- cycle;
%
\coordinate (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) ($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);
\coordinate (another_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) ($(B)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);
%
%\path[draw=black, fill=gray!50] (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) -- (another_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) -- (C) -- (E) -- cycle;
%
\draw[dashed, green] (A) -- (D);
\draw (D) -- (B);
\draw[dashed, green] (B) -- (E);
\draw (E) -- (C);
\draw (C) -- (A);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that your title is a bit misleading. There is also a latex package called `calc`, but use are using the `calc` tikz library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `\coordinate` is

```
\coordinate (<name>) at (<coordinate>);
```

you have

```
\coordinate (<name>) (<coordinate>);
```

and in this case the default coordinate, `(0,0)`, is used instead. Hence, your

```
\coordinate (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) ($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);
```

is the same as

```
\coordinate (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) at (0,0) ($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);
```

where the `($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$)` at the end doesn't really do anything useful. I guess it just sets the current point of the path to `($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$)`.

Note it is said explicitly in the manual that the `at` part of a coordinate specification can be omitted. This is from page 218 of the manual for 3.0.1a:

[image]

Comment: Wow.  That is embarrassing.

Comment: Why does the code compile?

Comment: There is no coordinate labeled `a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid`.

Comment: When I issue the command `\draw[green] (A) -- (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid);` why doesn't `TikZ` issue an error message?

Comment: @Adelyn Yes there is a coordinate named `a_vertex_..` you have defined it with `\coordinate (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) ($(A)!{(1/2)*(3 - sqrt(5))}!(D)$);`. But because `at` is missing (which the manual says is optional) that line becomes essentially the same as `\coordinate (a_vertex_of_isosceles_trapezoid) at (0,0);`

Comment: Thanks. Now I know if I get another unexpected rendition of my code, I will consider looking for a missing `at`.